# How comunicate with UART Transparent service BLE in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, bluetooth-gatt

I'm trying to do an app with xamarin which can communicate with a chip rn4870. This BLE chip uses UART Transparent services.  I'm new with bluetooth, so the most thing I read for do a communication with a ble device is to scan the device, connect it, looking for the service you want, get the characteristics and write,read or notify.

But, The most example I read, with heart rate device o smarthwath, the service is defined , for example a service for a battery, so, I can get the service, then the characteristic and read it. But with UART Transparent service, I get the `49535343-FE7D-4AE5-8FA9-9FAFD205E455` service to datatransfer, and then I get TX `49535343-1E4D-4BD9-BA61-23C647249616` and RX `49535343-8841-43F4-A8D4-ECBE34729BB3` characteristic but I don't know how to communicate.

Also I'm using plugin BLE of xamarin, with these plugin I can not see any particular function or documentation where I can use client/server functionality.

https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

So, if anyone has a idea how or which step I have to follow to can communicate with it and if you know how I could do it with xamarin, I will appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the UART transparent service the same way you would handle a battery service.

1. [Scan](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le#scan-for-devices) for available devices, even better if you use a filter to only find devices offering the UART service

```cs
adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s,a) => deviceList.Add(a.Device);
await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync(new[] { Guid.Parse("49535343-FE7D-4AE5-8FA9-9FAFD205E455"));
```

2. [Connect](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le#connect-to-device) to the device

```cs
try
{
    await _adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device);
}
catch(DeviceConnectionException e)
{
    // ... could not connect to device
}
```

3. [Get](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le#get-services) the UART service and both of the characteristics

```cs
var TX = await connectedDevice.GetServiceAsync(Guid.Parse("49535343-1E4D-4BD9-BA61-23C647249616"));
var RX = await connectedDevice.GetServiceAsync(Guid.Parse("49535343-8841-43F4-A8D4-ECBE34729BB3"));
```

4. [Enable notifications](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le#characteristic-notifications) on the TX characteristic to receive the answers and start [writing](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le#write-characteristic) to the RX characteristic

```cs
TX.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
{
    // Do something with the received value
    var bytes = args.Characteristic.Value;
};

await TX.StartUpdatesAsync();

await RX.WriteAsync(bytes);
```

If you want to test the connection and the communication procedure you can use a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile). Use it to search for your device and you can read, write and activate notifications with it.

There is also a [sample app](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/tree/master/Source/BLE.Client) using your xamarin plugin that offers this functionality:

> - check the ble status
> - discover devices
> - connect/disconnect
> - discover the services
> - discover the characteristics
> - see characteristic details
> - read/write and register for notifications of a characteristic